# Wordpress unable to communicate back to site

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to add a search box and the code I have so far is :

```
<div id="search"style="float-right;padding-right:30px;padding-top:25px;height:50px;width:500px">
<?php echo do_shortcode('wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]')?></div>
```

I keep getting the following message:

> Unable to communicate back with the site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

Comment: <div id="search"style="float-right;padding-right:30px;padding-top:25px;height:50px;width:500px">
 <?php echo do_shortcode('wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]')?></div>

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Change line 492 of wp-admin/includes/file.php:

FROM

if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension ) {

TO

if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension && false) {

It will work.

Comment: Hi thank you that worked fine by us, but could you explain what does it do ?
Because and the same question asked here: some people do not recommend to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192978/unable-to-communicate-back-with-site-to-check-for-fatal-errors

Comment: Personnaly the error is coming from file wp-admin/includes/file.php
It exits 2 tests, 1 with :
```$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout', 'sslverify' ) );```
and the other only:
```$r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout' ) );```

Just add ```, 'sslverify'``` in the second after time out and you should be able to push your files :)