# Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors

Tags: php, wordpress, header-files

Unable to communicate back with the site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

There is any Solution

I am editing in a header file in WordPress, Getting this problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I had the same issue and decided to look into it.

Change line 492 of wp-admin/includes/file.php:

FROM

if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension ) {

TO

if ( $is_active && 'php' === $extension && false) {

[Wordpress unable to communicate back to site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716853/wordpress-unable-to-communicate-back-to-site)

Comment: This makes the entire statement false and will be reverted anyways once you update Wordpress. Please do not do this!

Comment: This is a bandaid but is not the solution to the problem. It simply circumvents the issue. It's like having a headache so you cut your head off.

Comment: Editing files provided by external software is never a good idea

Comment: Error is coming from file wp-admin/includes/file.php It exits 2 tests, 1 with : $r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout', 'sslverify' ) ); and the other only: $r = wp_remote_get( $url, compact( 'cookies', 'headers', 'timeout' ) );

Just add , 'sslverify' in the second after time out and you should be able to push your files :)